# In the context of proper nouns, are there any examples in French where they are used as appellatives?

Tags: french, proper-nouns

There exists many examples of this in English, for example 'there are 3 Carolines in my class' or 'there are several Aberdeens in Scotland' (not true of course..just for example!).

I was wondering if there was the equivalent in French, particularly would you be able to apply plurality to given names as in my first example, or would this take on a different form in French? Would it have to be 'there are 3 people named Caroline..' in order to be grammatically correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question may be suited to French language stackexchange: http://french.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible in French too.

> Il y a trois Caroline dans ma classe.

In French, proper nouns never take a plural mark. The noun *Caroline* in that sentence is plural, but it is invariable. (This may be a mistake that natives make in this case, but I don't think it's raised to the point of being considered acceptable even by most descriptivists.) Similarly, the equivalent of “I visited the Joneses yesterday” in French would be “*j'ai rendu visite aux Dupont hier*”. “There are 18 Aberdeens in the United States” is “*Il y a 18 Aberdeen aux États-Unis*”.

There are a few exceptions to this rule. If the proper noun is used to evoke an archetype, then it does take a plural mark, even if it remains spelled with a capital letter: contrast “*des Picassos*” (some genius painters) with “*des Picasso*” (some people in a family whose surname is Picasso) or “*des Picasso*” (some paintings by Picasso). Also, a few historical surnames do take a plural mark (“*les Bourbons*”, “*les Horaces et le Curiaces*”). See also [Accord du nom de famille](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9048/accord-du-nom-de-famille).